# NodeJS never join on second await function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I've a main function that call other 2 functions with await.

1. The first one will download an image locally,
2. the second one will upload an image on our CDN with an Axios call, and wait his JSON response.

But when the first one will complete the main function going out, and not join on the second.
I need to join it
Note: Anyway the `console.log('Middle')` still never printed!

```
async function main(){
console.log('[1] Joined in the main()');

let url_immagine = 'https://www.castrol.com/content/dam/castrol/country-sites/en_gb/united-kingdom/home/motorcycle-engine-oils/engine-oil-brands/power1-racing-4t-10w-40.png.img.500.medium.png';
            

let filename = 'motor_oil.png';
let id = 122;
            
   await downloadImagefromRemote(url_immagine, filename);
   console.log('middle');
   await putImageOnCloud(id, filename);
}
```

this is my JSFiddle script:
[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/rpaf8n2t/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could just not await the second function.

```
putImageOnCloud(id, filename)
```

You say you dont want to wait for it, but you still use await.

Comment: I need to wait Axios response, becouse will return the hash of image uploaded

Comment: But you never put it in a variable?